# Javascript DOM .querySelector() null issue

Tags: javascript

I am writing code in plain JavaScript, there are lot of scenarios where I will use `querySelector()` method, I ran into issue multiple times like

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null" for the following code,

```
document.querySelector('.tab.active').classList.remove('active');
```

/** Tab not available at the time**/

In Jquery `$('.tab.active').removeClass('active');` will run only if the element is available without throwing error.

I want to achieve similar behavior in JavaScript. Please provide your ideas.

I am not willing to write three lines of code for every DOM operation I am doing, looking for one line code like Jquery.

```
var activeTab = document.querySelector('.tab.active');
if(activeTab !== 'null' ){
    activeTab.classList.remove('active'); 
}
```

Comment: `var el = document.querySelector(....); if (el) el.classList.remove('fdsafds');`

Comment: That's what jQuery is doing behind the scenes, it's converting the null result to an empty jQuery object. You'll have to do the same if you don't want to use jQuery.

Comment: You can use ternary operator for single line solution. 
`document.querySelector('.tab.active')1=='null ? document.querySelector('.tab.active').classList.remove('active') : '';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicitly checking for the existence of the element in your code as you're doing originally is surely the clearest way you could do it, but if you really don't want to, you could create your own function that, if no element is found, returns an object with methods that don't do anything. For example:

```js
const customQS = selector => (
  document.querySelector(selector)
  || {
    classList: {
      remove: () => void 0
    }
  }
);

customQS('.tab.active').classList.remove('active');
console.log('done, no error');
```

Of course, with that method, you'd have to create properties for each DOM method you'd want to use. A more robust option would be to *actually create* an element and return it, which would be more expensive, but the element will be garbage collected right afterward:

```js
const customQS = selector => (
  document.querySelector(selector)
  || document.createElement('div')
);

customQS('.tab.active').classList.remove('active');
console.log('done, no error');
```

Comment: Can you give more generic, please don't limit to only 'classList' attribute

Comment: You'll either have to actually create an element each time or make an object with all possible properties (and their methods) you'd want to access.