# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')

Tags: javascript

```js
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('section[id]')

function scrollActive(){
    const scrollY = window.pageYOffset

    sections.forEach(current =>{
        const sectionHeight = current.offsetHeight,
              sectionTop = current.offsetTop - 58,
              sectionId = current.getAttribute('id')

        if(scrollY > sectionTop && scrollY <= sectionTop + sectionHeight){
             document.querySelector('.nav__menu a[href*=' + sectionId + ']').classList.add("active")
        }else{
            document.querySelector('.nav__menu a[href*=' + sectionId + ']').classList.remove("active")
        }
    })
}
window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollActive)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript DOM .querySelector() null issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50921698/javascript-dom-queryselector-null-issue)

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelector` is not guaranteed to return an `Element`. If no matching element is found it will return null. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

So you're potentially saying: `null.classList.remove(...)`

Check that you've got an element from the `querySelector` before using it, e.g:

```js
const element = document.querySelector('.nav__menu a[href*=' + sectionId + ']')

if (!element) return; // early return

if (scrollY > sectionTop && scrollY <= sectionTop + sectionHeight){
    element.classList.add("active")
} else {
    element.classList.remove("active")
}
```